# Execute multiple queries in single Oracle command in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, plsql

I am using visual studio 2013 and oracle database.I want execute multiple create table queries at once in single oraclecommand is it possible ? I am trying following but not working

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "create table test(name varchar2(50) not null)"+"create table test2(name varchar2(50) not null)"; 
//+ "create table test3(name varchar2(50) not null)"+"create table test3(name varchar2(50) not null)";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Got error at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order to execute more than one command put them in `begin ... end;` block. 
And for DDL statements (like `create table`) run them with `execute immediate`. This code worked for me:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText =
    "begin " +
    "  execute immediate 'create table test1(name varchar2(50) not null)';" +
    "  execute immediate 'create table test2(name varchar2(50) not null)';" +
    "end;";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

More info: [Executing SQL Scripts with Oracle.ODP](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/executing-sql-scripts-with-oracle-odp/)

Comment: what would be the index of the first column of second query ? textbox1.Text = oraReder.GetString(index).ToString();

Comment: More info link is not available.

Comment: More info link from [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160725063714/http://www.intertech.com/Blog/executing-sql-scripts-with-oracle-odp/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
cmd.CommandText = "create table test(name varchar2(50) not null);"+"create table test2(name varchar2(50) not null);";
```

Comment: you might need a begin and end statement. "doesnt work" isnt helpful.

Comment: Tried with begin and end statement but same error. @BugFinder

Comment: Error message "An unhandled exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll " at ExecuteNonQuery(); @BugFinder

Comment: @BugFinder what would be the index of the first column of second query ? textbox1.Text = oraReder.GetString(index).ToString();