# Multiple delete statement in single query

Tags: oracle, ado.net

I am trying to execute the following functionality. But I am getting error as command not ended properly. But when I am executing in database it is executing properly:

```
 string sql = @"Delete FROM table1  WHERE idtest in (Select istest from table12 Where case_id=:caseID); 
                           Delete from table12 Where case_id=:caseID ;
                           Delete from table13 Where case_id=:caseID ;
                           Delete from table14 Where case_id=:caseID ;
                           Delete from table15 Where case_id=:caseID ;
                           ";

            using (OracleConnection Conn = new OracleConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    oh.InitOraConn(Conn);
                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("", Conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = Conn;
                        cmd.CommandText = sql;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("caseID", caseId);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    throw Ex;
                }
            }
```

So please guide what is wrong in it?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917301/execute-multiple-queries-in-single-oracle-command-in-c-sharp/31918260#31918260) will help.

Comment: Correct me everyone if I am wrong but you could wrap all your SQL in a PL/SQL block no?

Answer (score 0):

- You can only execute single SQL commands
- The `;` is not necessary

like this:

```
        using (OracleConnection Conn = new OracleConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                oh.InitOraConn(Conn);
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("", Conn))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = Conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = @"Delete FROM table1  WHERE idtest in (Select istest from table12 Where case_id=:caseID)";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("caseID", caseId);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.CommandText = @"Delete from table12 Where case_id=:caseID ";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("caseID", caseId);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    ... and so on

                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                throw Ex;
            }
        }
```

If you want something that is transactional with more tables and more logic, then you may consider building a stored procedure in your database and call it ^with your parameter.