# Executing an inline statement with stored procedure using Oracle.ManagedAccess

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

```
StringBuilder sql_statement  = new StringBuilder();

sql_statement.Append("sampleStoreproc(null, 1); ");
sql_statement.Append("SELECT 'Y' FROM myTable ");
sql_statement.Append("WHERE column1 = null AND column2 = 1 ");

DataAccessObject.ExecuteReader(
    connectionString, 
    CommandType.Text, 
    sql_statement.ToString());
```

It is throwing me error:

> ORA-0090 Invalid SQL statement

I have tried with adding `;` semicolon at the last of statement, but its not working.

I copied the whole text and putting in SQL Developer its perfectly executing.

Comment: Is Oracle likely to allow you to execute multiple statements in a single statement like this?

Comment: its a store procedure ,

Comment: I am new to oracle  , so I dont know if its allows or not

Comment: you can execute batches, but you need to observe the PL/SQL syntax rules strictly. for example, there is no semicolon after the second instruction, and IIRC you need to enclose batches in BEGIN .... END; also, the idiom for NULL comparison is `column1 IS NULL` instead of `column1 = null`.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/31918260/1132334

Answer (score 2):

In your first statement, you're calling a stored procedure. Change it to:

```
sql_statement.Append("execute sampleStoreproc(null, 1); ");
```

Also it is recommended to add a semicolon to the end of your last line.

**Edit:** Try enclosing both your statements in a `begin...end;` block:

```
sql_statement.Append("begin");
sql_statement.Append("  execute sampleStoreproc(null, 1);");
sql_statement.Append("  SELECT 'Y' FROM myTable");
sql_statement.Append("  WHERE column1 = null AND column2 = 1;");
sql_statement.Append("end;");
```

Comment: didnt work, using Oracle.ManagedAccess.dll for connection

Comment: Then try enclosing both your statements in a `begin...end;` block. See my updated answer.

Comment: Tried with begin end , I think its problem with Oracle.ManagedAccess.dll we are using for executing

Comment: When I am doing with BEGIN END , its saying it cant find function  "sampleStoreproc" , its clearly present

Comment: Oh, I think we should not use `execute` in a `begin...end;` block. Try without it.