# How to execute different multiple SQL statements using OracleCommand C#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle.manageddataaccess

I am trying to execute different SQL statements using OracleCommand.

```
var conn = new OracleConnection("User Id=SYSTEM;Password=mw;Data Source=SampleDataSource");
// Open the connection
if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    conn.Open();

string sql = @"
    DROP TABLE CUSTOMERS;

    CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
        ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        NAME VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
        AGE INT,
        ADDRESS VARCHAR(12)
    );

    INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) VALUES (1, 'Mark', 28, 'NY');

    INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) VALUES (2, 'John', 39, 'LA');

    INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) VALUES (3, 'Andy', 48, 'CA');

    INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) VALUES (4, 'Allan', 53, 'LA');
";

var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (OracleException e)
{
    error = e.Message;
}
finally
{
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception.

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

When I enclose the multiple statements in BEGIN, END block then I am getting the following exception.

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DROP" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with    << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
>   json_exists json_value json_query json_object json_array

Comment: Could you create a stored procedure and use execute immediate? You would have to use execute immediate to drop the table.

Comment: You could also try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917301/execute-multiple-queries-in-single-oracle-command-in-c-sharp

Comment: execute immediate is what you will need in order to call multiple statements

Comment: Might be irrelevant to Oracle but in MS SQL Server you can't do a drop and a create table and a query in the same batch. If Oracle has a batch separator like MSSQL's `GO` try putting that in between.

Comment: Typically you don't drop or create tables at runtime. What is your purpose?

Answer (score 2):

execute immediate will give you the ability to execute more than one statement.

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("User Id=SYSTEM;Password=mw;Data Source=SampleDataSource");  

if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    con.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText =
    "begin " +
    "  execute immediate 'DROP TABLE CUSTOMERS';" +
    "  execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,NAME VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL, AGE INT, ADDRESS VARCHAR(12))';" +
    "  execute immediate 'INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) VALUES (1, 'Mark', 28, 'NY')';" +
    "  execute immediate 'INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) VALUES (2, 'John', 39, 'LA')';" +
    "  execute immediate 'INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) VALUES (3, 'Andy', 48, 'CA')';" +
    "  execute immediate 'INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) VALUES (4, 'Allan', 53, 'LA')';" +
    "end;"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (OracleException e)
{
    error = e.Message;
}
finally
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO ...` does not require `execute immediate`

Comment: no, it's not working with only Drop and Create statements as well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better when you use a command for each statement.
Below is an example with [dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper).

```
  const string dropTableCustomers = "DROP TABLE CUSTOMERS";

  const string createTableCustomers = @"    
    CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    AGE INT,
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(12))";

  const string insertCustomerMark = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) VALUES (1, 'Mark', 28, 'NY')";
  const string insertCustomerJohn = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) VALUES (2, 'John', 39, 'LA')";

  using (var connection = new OracleConnection("User Id=SYSTEM;Password=mw;Data Source=SampleDataSource")) {
    connection.Open();

    connection.Execute(dropTableCustomers);
    connection.Execute(createTableCustomers);
    connection.Execute(insertCustomerMark);
    connection.Execute(insertCustomerJohn);
  }
```

If you need a transaction, you can do following:

```
  public static class DbConnectionFactory {
    public static IDbConnection Create(string connectionString) {
      var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
      connection.Open();

      return connection;
    }
  }


  const string dropTableCustomers = "DROP TABLE CUSTOMERS";

  const string createTableCustomers = @"    
    CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    AGE INT,
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(12))";

  const string insertCustomerMark = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) VALUES (1, 'Mark', 28, 'NY')";
  const string insertCustomerJohn = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) VALUES (2, 'John', 39, 'LA')";

  using (var connection = DbConnectionFactory.Create("User Id=SYSTEM;Password=mw;Data Source=SampleDataSource"))
  using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()) {

    connection.Execute(dropTableCustomers);
    connection.Execute(createTableCustomers);
    connection.Execute(insertCustomerMark);
    connection.Execute(insertCustomerJohn);

    transaction.Commit();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strSQL = @"Insert all into NEW1(a,b) VALUES(1,2) "
                + "INTO NEW1(a,b) VALUES(2, 3) "
                + "INTO NEW1(a,b) VALUES(3, 4) "
                + "INTO NEW2(a,b) VALUES(9, 9) "
                + "INTO NEW2(a,b) VALUES(6, 6) "
                + "SELECT * FROM DUAL";
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the DevArt library which has the DbScript Class inside, You can find a usage example at this URL: [DbScript Class](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data%7EDevart.Common.DbScript.html)