# Two Queries in one copy activity Data Factory v2

Tags: oracle, azure, oracle-adf, azure-data-factory

I'm new using Azure Data Factory and i would like to know if there is a mode to run two queries in one activity copy, for example:

I have a Data Set Oracle for my origin and other for my stage, both use Oracle DB.

i need copy all registries in a specific query, but before to run it, i need to alter session

```
ALTER session SET nls_language = 'AMERICAN';
```

and immediately run my query

```
Select * from ... where  ....
```

This is posible? or it's not the way? thks for your answers

**Important:** We don't have the posibility to create objects in DB Origin

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, in the copy activity, click on the tab Source, and then select Query. Input your 2 step query into the textbox and you are good to go.

[image: Query in copy activity]

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thks for your answer!

I have been trying to run copy with 2 queries in the same textbox, but doesn't work, i prove it in a copy activity and lookUp activity, after to run it, give me the next error

Failure happened on 'Source' side.ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-00911: invalid character,Source

the textbox have the script:

ALTER session SET nls_language = 'AMERICAN'; SELECT field1, field2 from table_x

All this in th same textbox

Comment: Sorry my answer would've worker for Sql Server, for Oracle maybe try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917301/execute-multiple-queries-in-single-oracle-command-in-c-sharp