# How can I run a big sql script with multiple commands to an Oracle database with c#?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I've already tried OracleCommand but it's designed for one command only.
The script is full of CREATE and procedures. There's a way to run this big script without re-designing it? Also I've tried microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo but it's not present in my machine.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917301/execute-multiple-queries-in-single-oracle-command-in-c-sharp/31918260#31918260) answer will help?

Comment: Already seen but there are 3900 lines of code so redesigning every subcommand with this tecnhique it will be a masive work. Also in the script there are begin-end procedures.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a script intended to be run from an Oracle client like SQL\*Plus. Why do you need to run it from C#?

Comment: I'm developing an installer, I could do this action with a Custom action calling sqlplus from c# or another enviroment, but doing so there will be the necessity to input the password. I would like to having all automatic.

Comment: How often will you have to run this script?  If this script is truly ginormous, or if the script changes frequently, it might be worth parsing the script and converting it to multiple SQL statements.  You could do that with my open source program [PLSQL_LEXER](https://github.com/method5/plsql_lexer).  It's not a full parser, but it's smart enough to know how to split statements and remove the terminators.  And it runs in any Oracle database and could be used to either generate C# commands or run SQL commands.  The downside is it's not trivial to install and use.

Comment: That would be a prerequisite for the installation. My objecetive is to use something already present on machine